# R: Subset of vector for multiple matches

Tags: r, vector, subset

I ran into a seemingly easy-to-solve problem today. This has been giving me headaches for more than an hour and I don't know how to solve this without having to implement a loop (which is time consuming and the opposite of elegant programming).

Given I have a set of numbers from 400 to 420 ("data"). Then there is a range, specified by the user. This range shall later become a subset of the data ("vector_subset"). Also, there is a vector with numbers to be excluded from the data ("vector_substract").

This is what I get:

```
data <- seq(400,420)
vector_subset <- seq(405,412)
vector_substract <- c(402,403,404,405,408,409,412,413,414)
```

now I want to find which elements I need to extract, because they are both in the user subset vector and the substraction vector:

```
intersection <- intersect(vector_subset, vector_substract)
```

This works just fine:

```
> intersection
[1] 405 408 409 412
```

Now I want to exclude these values from the "data" vector. But if I try this:

```
result <- data[-which(data==intersection)]
```

R tells me that

> In data == intersection :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

If I delete one element at a time, it works fine. Like:

```
result <- data[-which(data==intersection[1])]
> result
 [1] 400 401 402 403 404 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420
```

-> first entry of "intersection" is gone (405).

So I could implement a for-loop and delete entry by entry, but that would take too long. Is there a better way to build my desired subset?

Thanks to all helpers!

Answer (score 2):

Just use usual set operations:

```
setdiff(data, intersect(vector_subset, vector_substract))
#[1] 400 401 402 403 404 406 407 410 411 413 414 415 416 417 418 419 420
```

Comment: although it supposed there is no duplicate in the former data that you wish to keep, like `setdiff(c(1:4, 4:8), c(1,2,7))` will give back just one 4.

Comment: No. It returns 3 4 5 6 8

Comment: yes so just one 4 instead of 2 in the original data (but it does indeed return the other numbers - sorry, there was not clear in my comment). But, anyway, in the example data there is no duplicate so your answer is the best (that was what the "although" was for in my comment, it followed the upvote ;-) )